# Nodelist message setString property

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jms

heyho :)
i have a nodelist which finds multiple nodes like

```
NodeList nodelist = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//name/text()", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(nodelist.getLength());
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.getLength(); i++) {
                        list.add(nodelist.item(i).getNodeValue());
                        message.setStringProperty("name", nodelist.item(i).getNodeValue());}
```

and an xml like

```
<name>Peter</name>
<name>John</name>
```

so when i send the message it should give out

```
<usr><name>Peter</name><name>John</name></usr>
```

but it just returns john. (of course because it first gets peter, and then replaces peter with john, like a girl :D)
but i wondered how i could get aswell peter as john in the usrheader i ried with adding a number to the node name, but thats darn unpretty and in the end it just should say

```
<usr><name>Peter</name><name>John</name></usr>
```

any idea how to fix that it just gives out one name and not both?

xpath.getClass().getCanonicalName() returns com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl

Comment: Please comment what `xpath.getClass().getCanonicalName()` gives.

Comment: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl